# The Reality Of Tie

Tags: muslim-practices

We wear necktie with our suits normally when we go to office or school. Does tie resmeble in any form to 'Cross of Christianity'? If so then should we wear it or not?

Many 'Fatwas' are in favour and many are against. Can someone shed light into it by referring to quran and hadith?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. You already researched it and viewed both opinions, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @American Muslim,I viewed 'Fatwas' but as i do not posess the full knowledge of islam so i was unable to decide which 'Fatwa' is correct as both had strong arguments therefore i believe that this site may have users who could give more insight to it as i am finding it difficult to search on this topic on the internet as well. Moreover,this will only help viewers who may come up with  a similar question in future.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is valid and I want to give you answer of your question.
Can you find the verse in Bible where written that wearing tie is haram or it is the sign of Christianity?
Wearing of tie was introduced from Bosnia. In Bosnia, Muslims lived in this place. Any culture which are against our Shariah, it is haraam.

Let me give you example that Arabs wear tops and Christians also wear tops.
Then according to your point of view the tops are haraam or it is the sign of Christianity.

So, definitely tops are not haraam or sign of Christianity then how you say that tie is the sign of Christianity or haraam.

It is *Mubaah*. *Mubaah* means if you like it you can wear it and if you don't like then you can't wear it. It is your choice.

It is the misconception of some Muslims that wearing tie is the sign of Christianity.

Allah knows better.

I hope you satisfy with my answer.
Please follow watch this link, you can better understand from
[Dr Zakir Naik's Answer](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1ao0f4_dr-zakir-naik-islam-men-coat-tie-mpg-176x144_shortfilms)